# Java Applet works fine in Eclipse but in terminal(Appletviewer) not correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, applet

I am working on text analyser applet for my term assessment. I have finished and it works fine on eclipse(run java applet) but when I run it in terminal with appletviewer applet does not work correctly. I have run method with timer which repaints 60times/sec and in paint method I have 4 polygons acts as a tabs. when you click tab polygon appears on screen. With eclipse all good but with appletviewer in terminal it does not stays on one tab. Applet constantly changes tabs. Can't post a code at the moment because its assessment work. Do you have any idea why its appears differently in eclipse and terminal? (I used only standart java classes)

Comment: There is very little chance of anyone being able to answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: *"Can't post a code at the moment because its assessment work."*  We don't want to see your 'secret' code, but a minimal example that reproduces the problem.  To put that another way.  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score -1):

Try update-alternative and set your appletviewer.